# How to query a table and display NULL on the joined table if it does not meet the filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my data:

Vacation
-has Organizer column

Itinerary

ItineraryPayment
- this is a cross table with Itinerary and LK_Payment. just assume that it's the name
-has PaymentStatus

What I want to do is to be able to select the organizer column in Vacation and if the ItineraryPayment will be null or has a value depending if the Vacation has an Itinerary linked to it. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide table structure?

Comment: If you are intersested here is an online course (http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=IntroToDatabases) that i found very good, it should help you understand more about databases and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said:

```
select v.organizer, (cases i.vacation_id is null then i.value else null end)
from Vacation as v
left join itinerary as i
   on v.vacation_id = i.vacation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this URL for Joins in SQL server.

[JOINS IN SQL](http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial/sql_outer_join.cfm)

You will get the NULL values using.

Left Join or Right Join